# How to use NSFNoteCipherDecrypt in LotusScript agent

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm hoping to be able to use `NSFNoteCipherDecrypt` in a **LotusScript** agent to decrypt any encrypt messages found in selected mail databases, but I don't understand why I need to pass the `KFHANDLE` parameter to the function.

The API Reference database describes it as:

"hKFC - Handle to an ID file. Pass NULLKFHANDLE for current user's ID"

```
STATUS LNPUBLIC NSFNoteCipherDecrypt(
NOTEHANDLE hNote,
KFHANDLE hKFC,
DWORD DecryptFlags,
CIPHERHANDLE far *rethCipherForAttachments,
DWORD Reserved,
void *pReserved);
```

I can't find any references to using the function in a LotusScript agent, so I don't know what data types to use in its parameters:

```
Declare Private Function NSFNoteCipherDecrypt Lib "nnotes.dll" (ByVal hNote As Long, ByVal hKFC As ??? , ByVal DecryptFlags As ???, ByVal rethCipherForAttachments As ???, ByVal ???, ByVal ???) As Integer
```

**Is there a Notes C API master out there who can advise?**

Answer (score 1):

to get KFHANDLE use SECKFMOpen. You basically need to have an id file of the user the mail db belongs to and a password to it.

Unless it's the current user ID then you can pass NULL (i.e 0 ByVal).

A good starting point would be to write C code and get the mails decrypted; then you can figure out how to move it LS.

If you are going to use rethCipherAttachments you will pass it by ref.

Comment: And note: You are going to have to have the id files for each mailfile in an accessible place - with known passwords. This pretty much automatically creates a security risk. If you're using the ID Vault feature, there may be a secure way to do this securely (as long as you delete your temp files!), but the last time I looked into there was no published API for extracting IDs from the vault.

Comment: Thank you, Normunds and Richard. I can extract an ID file from the vault but the password is the showstopper for an agent that's going to run on a batch of mail users. I think we'll just have to scan the primary and archive email databases of our users and send them a report of any encrypted messages found, for them to deal with themselves (we can include in the report a Decrypt button that uses the API function).

Comment: One issue though is our (hundreds of) iNotes users, who would not see that button; an administrator might have to get each relevant user id from the vault then run the decryption process in the mail database (although I'm not sure it's going to be that simple to identify the iNotes users). Our mail is being migrated to Exchange so encrypted messages need to be decrypted first, otherwise they will no longer be accessible. Unless anyone has other ideas...